# Node Architecture with Multiple Mongo DBs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2, database-design, architecture

We have a SaaS platform that allows clients to create new Instances and a separate DB when they sign up. The issue is **creating a new instance** for every new client is expensive and difficult to maintain.

We have one easy solution -

- Merge all DBs into one and re-write the code accordingly (expensive to complete and we want to keep client DBs separate)

Ideally,

- We would want to have separate DBs but **common application instance** as it's easy to maintain and lowers our server costs significantly.

Is there a proper way so that the application runs a single instance but connects with different DBs as per the client logged in? And what would be its performance implications compared to both separate instances and separate DB?

[What we Have Already](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svDWC.png)

[What we Want Ideally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To6pO.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think that one instance which connects to a huge number of DBs might not be a good fit (it may quickly become a bottleneck).

Another (maybe better) middle-ground option would be to have multiple multi-tenant instances (each instance is able to process requests from multiple clients).

That way, you spread the inbound load more efficiently (because you'll have less instances than the number of clients, but more than one in order to avoid a bottleneck), but also the outbound traffic will be distributed, because one multi-tenant instance might not have to be connected to all DBs, but to a subset of them (depending on which client is logged-in).

One important vector here is the throughput that you get per tenant. Depending on that, you may decide whether one instance is enough, or you need to add more of them.